# Sencha Touch associated model fetching

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

I have a model "Order" that "hasMany" "Item"s

I get a push notification from my server that a new Item has been added to the Order. I also get the new Item's id. Now, I'd like to fetch that Item (from the server) and then add it to the Order.items() store ***locally*** i.e. I don't want sync to happen on the store – the store after the add should assume that it has the fresh data and should not feel the need to contact the server to "sync" anything.

Any thoughts on how I should approach this? Thanks!

Comment: so you are already handling push notifications? why not do model.load(itemId,{callback : function (record){//add record to store }})

Comment: I did that, but the store seems to be trying to sync it again. Is it not supposed to try to sync on add if I do a load on the model?